# How do I know if my data was decrypted correctly?

Tags: kotlin, encryption, aes, rsa

Im using the Cipher class in the java.security library to encrypt and decrypt data. Im specifically using RSA encryption to encrypt AES parameters and message byte length, the AES cipher is what I'm using to encrypt the message itself. Currently I have a problem that I can't be sure if the provided encrypted AES parameters and message length were encrypted with my RSA key, or if they were encrypted at all and not just random jiberish.

```
val rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
val rsaDecoded = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedAesParametersAndMessageLength)
val aesParameters = ByteArray(48)
val messageLength = ByteArray(4)
for (i in aesParameters.indices) {
    aesParameters[i] = rsaDecoded[i]
}
for (i in messageLength.indices) {
    messageLength[i] = rsaDecoded[i + aesParameters.size]
}

val length = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageLength).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).int
val aesEncryptor = AesEncryptor(aesParameters)
//bytes of the encryptedMessage
//TODO Make sure this doesn't result in an error
val encryptedMessage = ByteArray(length)
```

When trying to decrypt AES parameters and message length using the RSA key it doesn't throw any kind of exception if the data wasn't decrypted correctly. Eventually this leads to a memory overflow error because the message length is too large. Is it safe to maybe put a 4 bytes(holding some constant int value) after these parameters that i can check to make sure the data was decrypted correctly, or would that risk my apps safety?

Comment: Huh? Generally `"RSA"` means `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`, so it actually **should** throw an error. What runtime / encryption provider are you using?  (You can get this information from your `Cipher` object). Personally I'd try and specify above full algorithms string explicitly, and your code should now throw during unpadding, as part of the decryption routine.

Comment: With Android, this behavior would not be surprising: Providers on Android often apply `NoPadding` if padding is not explicitly specified. In this case, no exception would be thrown in case of an incorrect decryption.